# Eliminating multiple loops with more efficient algorithms; specifically alphabet arrays

Tags: c#, performance, loops

I know its labor day.  I got bored and started a "Code Fight Challenge."  Although I am a crm dev (mid) in work life, I have been doing lots of the operations and maint. side rather than deving.  Therefore, I am a bit rusty and like to get at least a "Code Fight" challenge in a day now to revamp.  The prob is not my logic, but performance.

Basically it is a reverse challenge and had to figure rules myself (which I did) the prob is it as to run in under 3ms:

Question is this pretty much this:  please make

> "ThISisaVEryLonGStrIngggGGGgGisnTiT314159265"

This...

> "KyZJzjrMVipCfeXJkiZexxxXXXxXzjeKzK"

Again my logic is sound but I seem to be looping alot and this is causing perf issue.  Without explicitly telling me what to do, may somone provide some documentation for me to read to improve my code (greatly):

```
    static string alphaChange(string s)
    {
        int number;
        bool result;
        string temp;
        int index = 0;
        string[] aDigits = new string[100/*s.Length*/];
        string ans = Regex.Replace(s, @"\d", string.Empty);
        string concat="";
        int adder = 0;
        char[] alphabet = new char[] {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        char[] alphabet2 = new char[] { 'A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            temp = c.ToString();
            result = Int32.TryParse(temp, out number);

            if(result)
            {
                aDigits[index] = Convert.ToString(temp);
                index++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < aDigits.Length; i++ )
        {
            concat += Convert.ToString(aDigits[i]);

        }

        adder = Convert.ToInt32(concat);
        var charArr = ans.ToCharArray();
        string finalAnswer = "";


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++ )

            for(int j = 0; j<alphabet.Length; j++)
            {
                if (charArr[i].ToString() == alphabet[j].ToString() || charArr[i].ToString() == alphabet2[j].ToString())
                {
                    int tempAdder = j;
                    for(int k = 0; k < adder; k++)
                    {
                        tempAdder++;
                        if(tempAdder > alphabet.Length - 1)
                        {
                            tempAdder = 0;
                        }

                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(tempAdder.ToString());
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                    if(charArr[i] == alphabet[j])
                    {
                        finalAnswer += alphabet[tempAdder];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finalAnswer += alphabet2[tempAdder];
                    }

                }


        }
              Console.WriteLine(finalAnswer);
              Console.ReadLine();

            return finalAnswer;
        }
```

**EDIT (PER COMMENT):**

string input = "wHaT111" string ouput = "dOhA" Take the number within the string and add that many characters to only the letters in input string. ie.  input "aaa1" would equal output "bbb"

Comment: You say "please make X into Y" but don't explain the rules. Also not sure this is a good fit for SO anyway.

Comment: why would performance not be a good fit for SO?

Comment: @DavidG Dude, you vote to close bc you can't answer my question?  lol...its ovbious im here for perf issues....please look at title again and possilbly direct me to some documentation to eliminate multiple nested loops when dealing with the alphabet...I was think something with bytes or something

Comment: Firstly I did NOT vote to close (yet) so don't make assumptions. Secondly the downvote was probably because you didn't explain your question in the first place. Finally, this is just a basic rotation cipher which has been done countless times before. Go look up ROT13 or Ceasar chipher for more info

Comment: this is not basic to me...thats why Im here asking a question...I obviously got the logi,  I have been on multiple forums and the rotation cipher keeps comeing up...also notice I didn't ask for the code, I only asked for some documentation where I could learn myself

Comment: If rotation cipher already came up, then why didn't you go look at it?

Comment: Well I tried to help by pointing you in the right direction and your immediate response was to accuse me of something I didn't do (even though it was a reasonable thing to have done) and now you resort to name calling. I guess some people are beyond help.

Comment: My fault...its easy to accuse people of down votes on here.  I feel that its bc one often thinks the "1" person that answers that challenges, is the only person whous viewed when in reality you had 10+

Comment: @JeffOrris please don't use words like dude or douche on SO. Working code questions are usually a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Slai My apologies, "code review" exchange completely slipped my mind

Answer (score 5):

This can be very succinctly done with no explicit loops by exploiting a bit of regex, linq and the modulo (`%`) operator (gets the remainder of a division).

Don't forget that a `char` can be treated as a numeric type, allowing (strange-looking) arithmetic on `char` values. For instance

```
('A' + 1) == 66; //true
```

and casting back

```
(char)('A' + 1) == 'B' //true
```

Using this `char` arithmetic, we can get zero based number of the character in the alphabet by subtracting 65 (`'A'`) for uppercase, and 97 (`'a'`) for lowercase.

This means that we can convert each character to its alphabet position (so `A` becomes `0`, `B` becomes `1` etc).

Now we add the key number, wrapping every 26. Mathematically, this can be stated as the remainder of (the alphabet-position added to the key number), all divided by 26. *This eliminates the cost of having to count out the additions individually in a loop, resetting to zero every 26 iterations.*

Now, we add back 65 or 97 to this alphabet position, depending on the case of the original char. This gives the the decoded character number (as an int), which we convert back to a char with the cast in the last `Select` below.

```
string Decode(string input)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<code>^[a-zA-Z]*?)(?<key>\d+)$");
    if(!match.Success)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    var num = int.Parse(match.Groups["key"].Value);
    var code = match.Groups["code"].Value;

    var newChars = code
                    .Select(c => c < 'a' //true: uppercase
                                 ? 'A' + ((c - 'A') + num) % 26 
                                 : 'a' + ((c - 'a') + num) % 26)
                    .Select(c => (char)c);
    return string.Concat(newChars);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of regex there, didn't know you could do that. I'd be tempted to do the char cast inside the first select though, to avoid a double loop.

Comment: @DavidG : The number of chars is trivial, so I'm not that focused on the performance, especially as this will already destroy the original implementation in terms of perf.

Comment: plus one for use of `<code>` and `<key>` groups in regex.

Answer (score 1):

1. charArr[i].ToString() == alphabet[j].ToString() why ToString?
2. ```
              int tempAdder = j;
               for(int k = 0; k < adder; k++)
               {
                   tempAdder++;
                   if(tempAdder > alphabet.Length - 1)
                   {
                       tempAdder = 0;
                   }

               }
   ```

This can easily be done by simple calculation!

3. string concatenation with += gives you probably a lot of GC's. Use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of a loop simply by using a dictionary. so instead of
 char[] alphabet and char[] alphabet2 , you need

```
var dictionary =   new Dictionary<char, char>();
    dictionary.Add('a', 'x');
    dictionary.Add('A', 'X');
```

Also, as far as I understand, you want to get ride of duplicates that are after each other like "xx ".
you can implement every thing with one loop.

```
// var lastChar= something
 foreach (var item in charArr)
 { 
   var newchar =dictionary[item];
   if(newchar == lastChar)
     finalAnswer += newchar;
     lastChar= newChar;
 }
```

Comment: Ahhh dude...I totallu tough about the dictionary, but how much would this cut perforamce? +1

Comment: @JeffOrris one point is to choose the dictionary. your code's order is O(n^3) which is horrible. I have only one loop which is o(n). since the dictionary itself is from o(1) check this link for performance http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time

Answer (score 1):

This should be the fastest:

```
static string alphaChange(string s)
{
    int L = s.Length;
    var ca = new char[L];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < L;) // optional loop if any numbers before letters
    {
        int start = i;
        while ( i < L && ( s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9' ) ) i++; // find index of first digit
        int end = i;

        int shift = 0;
        while ( i < L && s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9' ) shift = shift * 10 + s[i++] - '0';
        shift %= 26;

        for (int ci = start; ci < end; ci++) {
            var c = s[ci];
            var max = 'Z';
            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') max = 'z';
            else if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue; // optional just in case 

            var a = c + shift;
            if (a > max) a -= 26;
            ca[count++] = (char)a;
        }
    }        
    return new string(ca, 0, count);
}
```

Not sure if required, but your code might give wrong result if any of the numbers are between letters.